# NPM workspace and VSCode node_modules path

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, npm-workspaces

I am using npm workspaces with typescript as specified in this git README https://github.com/Quramy/npm-ts-workspaces-example

When I do `npm i` from the project root directory it installs all packages in root directory (node_modules). It doesn't create `node_modules` directory in each workspace. Because of this, VSCode thinks 'module' is missing `(Cannot find module 'abcde' or its corresponding type declarations)`, hence shows red under line on import line and doesn't show auto complete suggestion.

How can I make VSCode understand that packages are installed in root folder and use it for giving auto complete suggestion and remove red underlines under package import.

Comment: Are you opening the individual `package` directory with VSCode or the root of your project? If not, try opening the root of the project where the main `node_modules` directory is.

Comment: I am open root dir.

Comment: I have this same issue. Even when opening VSCode from the root, the language server only looks in the nearest node_modules to resolve and does not visit the project root.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when turning an existing project into a workspace of a larger project. Here are the steps that worked for me:

1. Delete `package-lock.json` and `node_modules/` from the subdirectory
2. Restart VSCode, opening it to the project's new root directory

I think step (2) was the key to making it work, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: this didnt help, in fact there was no `package-lock.json` or `node_modules/` in subfolders